# react-native run-android failed in new init project

Tags: react-native

I trying to create new react-native project by`react-native init Project`, then `react-native run-android` . However I getting the error below [image]

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.62.2
node v12.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install JDK 1.8 version and make as JAVA_HOME in enviroment_variable and then try. it should work